# How to priorize eventhandling (LIBGDX)

Tags: libgdx

I have a Screen:

```
WorldScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor{

    ....
    stageGui.addActor(storyActor);
    ....

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    }

}
```

and I have an Actor :

```
public class StoryActor extends Group {
private InputListener listener = new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            event.handle();
        }
}
}
```

When Clicking on the actor, then first the touchup from the WorldScreen is handled. Then later the touchUp from the StoryActor is handled.

How can I achieve that first the actors will be handled ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of implementing InputProcessor in your WorldScreen. Create a new class for InputProcessor for example: `WorldScreenInputProcessor implements InputProcessor`

After that, you can use the InputMultiplexer to handle several InputProcessors:

```
InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();

//What you add first has higher priority
multiplexer.addProcessor(stageGui); //Input of your Actor
multiplexer.addProcessor(new WorldScreenInputProcessor());

Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling#inputmultiplexer on how to use input multiplexers it should solve your problem.